# Ubuntu 13.04 invert touch pad scroll direction

Tags: 13.04, drivers, touchpad

after being away from ubuntu for a while and being used to an inverted touchpad scrolling, I have recently jumped on ubuntu 13.04 bandwagon again. I have being having a hard time and am wondering if it is possible to invert?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is called "natural scrolling".

**From 14.04 on** you can toggle that behavior from *System Settings*/*Mouse-Touchpad*

[image: screenshot]
(thx to Iceman for pointing this out)

**For earlier versions** there is no immediate GUI tool but you can achieve it with [dconf-editor [image: Install dconf-editor]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-editor).

From the dash open `dconf-editor`, on the left side select `org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/touchpad
[image: screenshot]

There you check *natural-scroll*

Comment: I love you people!

Comment: Since I was searching for the same thing, I just wanted to comment and say this is now (from 14.04) possible in the 'System Settings -> Mouse/Touchpad' GUI.

Comment: @Iceman thx for pointing this out, I added it to my answer.