# Ubuntu 14.04: Touch pad scroll direction is wrong on Dell Latitude and Lenovo ThinkPad

Tags: dell, touchpad, lenovo, thinkpad

I have installed 14.04 recently in my Dell Latitude E6410.
Touch pad scroll working seems to be incorrect. Inverted direction.

I checked this on Lenovo ThinkPad also, there also i have observed the same.

Expects a positive response soon. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 13.04 invert touch pad scroll direction](http://askubuntu.com/questions/329880/ubuntu-13-04-invert-touch-pad-scroll-direction)

Answer (score 4):

go to Mouse & Touchpad settings and check/uncheck 'Natural scrolling' and see which works for you

Comment: Same issue for me, with a Dell E7470... unfortunatly, there is no 'Natural scrolling' option in my Mouse and Touchpad settings

Comment: Same issue with Dell Precision 7510, stupid *natural* scrolling is default by hardware but no option to turn it off